# Changing the image in Facebook "Post to wall" page iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sharekit

I had integrated Facebook in my iphone app using Sharekit.

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com"];

    shareScore_ = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Sample Post"];

    [SHKFacebook shareItem:shareScore_];
```

How can i change the icon in the Facebook "Post to Wall" view. Now the icon automatically displayed is the icon of my website `http://www.mywebsite.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy, if you use [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/).

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com"];
NSString *pictureURI = @"http://www.mywebsite.com/picture.jpg";

shareScore_ = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Sample Post"];
shareScore_.facebookURLSharePictureURI = pictureURI;

[SHKFacebook shareItem:shareScore_];
```

More info is in `SHKItem.h` and `DefaultSHKConfigurator.m`

If you are new to [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/), the install is quite different than original shareKit. Make sure, that you follow installation wiki carefully.